# Can not convert from Google's given duration in ISO 8601 format to C# TimeSpan

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, duration, iso8601

I get data from Google for "[introductoryPricePeriod](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html)". I am using UnityPurchasing module in my Game. The "introductoryPricePeriod" duration show up as "P12W6D" which means 12 weeks 6 days. It is in ISO 8601 format. I am unable to parse this to a TimeSpan in C#
[image]

What i already tried which does not work is:

```
System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("P12W6D");
```

I read the wikipedia page for [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format and it says the format can be only be of the form "PnYnMnDTnHnMnS". This does not contains the "W" key word for weeks. It contains another keyword "PnW" but it is only for weeks. Is Google sending me an incorrect format? Should google send me "P12W6D" as "P3M6D" ? because i tested it and "P3M6D" works. It gets easily converted to 96.00:00:00 Timespan. The only problems is with the "W" keyword.

Comment: That does seem odd :-/ One option would be to take the source for [Mono's XsdDuration class](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Xml/System/Xml/Schema/XsdDuration.cs) (which does the actual parse for XmlConvert) and enhance it yourself to support weeks too. Or parse out W and D yourself, and add W*7 to the D value, then parse that. And maybe worth asking Google or UnityPurchasing about this too if you can since they're giving you the bad data.

Comment: side note; How many days in a month? I never liked the fact that duration allows you to specify an ambiguous value.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Turns out it's 30 :-( C#'s TimeSpan only supports numbers of days, not days and months, so XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan here just uses 30 days per month. Which is wrong.

Comment: @Rup Is there really another choice? A year is also problematic - is it 365 or 366 days? What about a minute? Is it 60 or 61 seconds (though leap seconds are rare and usually considered insignificant enough to simply ignore)

Comment: @ZoharPeled The other choice is to keep years and months separate from days and at the point you add them to a date then add a whole number of months etc. Which is probably what you want here for a trial period expiry date: you want start + whole number of months. I think NodaTime's Period does this, at first glance. But I realise you're always going to have to do some rounding at some point e.g. if you want to sort Period(1 month) into a list of periods just specified as days.

Comment: @Rup - Well, that's quite true - a duration *might* be unambiguous when you know the start time -  but even that's not always enough. For instance, [the October revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_Revolution) actually happened in November (Well, depending on who you ask) - My point is that people tend to underestimate the amount of over-complication other people have burdened time measurements with.

Comment: @Rup I have to enhance myself as it is the only option. Yes i will ask google too. Thanks for your time and help!